# how to print a specific column but ignoring first 10 lines and last 10 lines in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I want to print 2nd column but i don't want first 10 and last 10 lines.

```
 awk 'NR>10' filename.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'| head --lines=-10
```

It didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
tail -n+11 filename.txt | head -n-10 | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Input**

```
$cat lines_1-40.txt
line 1 in the file
line 2 in the file
line 3 in the file
line 4 in the file
...
line 38 in the file
line 39 in the file
line 40 in the file
```

**Output**

```
$ tail -n+11 lines_1-40.txt | head -n-10 | awk '{print $2}'
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```